# How to check the duration of a login session in 12.04

Tags: 12.04, login

Ok how do I know the the number/hours I have logged in? I just want to know the time I have spent since I logged in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can check when you logged in with the `last` command, it shows login time, when the session ended, and other useful bits of information.

You can use it by typing, for example: `last username -1` where username is your own username, which will show your most recent login. It should say 'still logged in' on the right.

If it's not the correct session, you can display more by changing the number in the command, such as `last username -5`.

Or to show all sessions still logged in, `last username | grep "still logged in"`

Comment: Thanks! Don't know why the login info isn't in the system monitor app

Comment: Thanks for the tips. Just updating for in 16.04 command, without username and different grep expression: last | grep "still running"